# porting ROS onto an autonomous Robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am working for sometime now (around 4 weeks) to try and port ROS onto a robot we have built using the Raspberry Pi as the main controller. This Robot has a variety of peripherals on it like a USB camera , Wifi Router, etc. All the peripherals are connected to the RPi (main controller) using I2C connectors. I am attempting to port the ROS onto this custom built robot. All the drivers for this robot are functional as such. But how do I get the robot vehicle to run ROS. Please let me know of some effective starting point/ link. I know that in this forum many have already done what I intend to do, please help me to get started in the right direction. Until now I have got ROS installed on my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop and onto an RPi board. I am currently working on the ROS basics tutorial, however it does'nt seem to cover, how to port ROS onto a custom built autonomous robot.

As part of this porting procedure, I feel that I need to do this step by step, as a result I am trying to first get ROS on the RPi working between a switch and an LED as a publisher/subscriber. I am not sure, how I need to go about doing this. Please let me know if my approach to solve the porting problem is correct too.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65975/porting-ros-onto-an-autonomous-robot/) by [Praseen](https://answers.ros.org/users/5042/praseen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should write some nodes for control that can interface between ROS and your motor controller. I don't know if your robot uses differential drive but if so you can look for instance at the [differential drive package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/differential_drive). Your own motor node should then accept the motor_cmd commands this node generates.
Next step would be to generate a urdf model of your robot so you can use transforms.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0